# The CSS for my navigation bar component is no working and instead is taking the CSS of my log in component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap, spotify

I am creating a website that utilizes the Spotify API and I have created a login page where the user can login through Spotify and if they successfully login they are redirected to my home page. I have CSS for the login that puts the login button in the center of the page and when they get redirected to the homepage I am trying to put the navigation bar on top of the page but for some reason, it takes the CSS of the Login component and ignores all the CSS I try to put in for the navigation bar component and I want to know why that is.

my App.js file:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Container } from 'react-bootstrap';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './App.css';
import Login from './components/Login';
import Home from  './components/Home';
import NavBar from './components/NavBar';
import Guesser from './components/Guesser';
import Feed from './components/Feed';
import Generator from './components/Generator';

const code = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('code')

const App = () => {
  
  return (
    <div className='main-content'>
      <Container>
        {code ? 
          <div>
            <Routes>
                <Route path='/' element={<NavBar />}>
                  <Route index element={<Home />} />
                  <Route path='/guesser' element={<Guesser />} />
                  <Route path='/feed' element={<Feed />} />
                  <Route path='/generator' element={<Generator />} />
                </Route>
            </Routes>
          </div> : 
          <Login />}
      </Container>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

my App.css file:

```
.main-content{
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  color:white;
  padding: 0;
}
```

My Login.js File:

```
import React from 'react'
import {Button} from 'react-bootstrap'; 
import "./index.css"
import SpotifyLogo from '../../spotify-logo2.png';

const Login = () => {
    const authEndPoint = "https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize";
    const clientId = "{My client id}";
    const redirectUri = "http://localhost:3000";
    const scopes = [
        "streaming",
        "user-read-email",
        "user-read-private",
        "user-library-read",
        "user-library-modify",
        "user-read-playback-state",
        "user-modify-playback-state"
    ];
    
    const AUTH_URL = `${authEndPoint}?client_id=${clientId}&response_type=code&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}&scope=${scopes.join("%20")}`;

    return(
        <div className="main-content">
            <div className='spot-img'>
                <img src={SpotifyLogo} alt='Spotify Logo'/>
            </div>
            <Button
                href={AUTH_URL}
                className='button'
            >
                login
            </Button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Login
```

My Login.css File:

```
.main-content{
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
}

.spot-img{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
}

.button{
    background-color: green;
    width: 100px;
}
```

My Navbar.js File:

```
import "./index.css";
import { NavLink, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const NavBar = () => {
    return(
        <div className='main-content'>
                <nav >
                    <NavLink
                        exact='true'
                        activeclassname='active'
                        to='/'
                    >
                        Home
                    </NavLink> |
                    <NavLink
                        exact='true'
                        activeclassname='active'
                        to='/guesser'
                    >
                        Guesser
                    </NavLink> | 
                    <NavLink
                        exact='true'
                        activeclassname='active'
                        to='/feed'
                    >
                        Feed
                    </NavLink> | 
                    <NavLink
                        exact='true'
                        activeclassname='active'
                        to='/Generator'
                    >
                        Generator
                    </NavLink> | 
                </nav> 
                <Outlet />           
        </div>
    )
}

export default NavBar;
```

My NavBar.css File:

```
.nagivation{
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    background-color: gray;
}
```

All the other component file are simple and only output the name of the webpage and have no CSS filed in yet.

[Login image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpYCc.png)

[Home page after successfully logging in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Txhg.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are reusing the same CSS for the logo and the navbar. The parent div of both the logo and the navbar uses the `.main-content` which centers everything

```
.main-content{
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
}
```

I suggest you use different styling for the parent div of your navbar.